# Jquery Load an external image with interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change an image from an external url and I did this:

```
var imgPaht = "http://www.sito.it/webcam.jpg";
$('<img src="'+ imgPaht +'">').load(function() {
    $(this).width(270).height(250).appendTo('#webcam');
});
```

It works but I would like to repeat this action with an interval of 5 seconds. I tried setting the interval but I probably did something wrong. Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(load, 5000);
    var imgPaht = "http://www.miosito.it/webcam.jpg";
    function load() {
        $('<img src="'+ imgPaht +'">').load(function () {
            $(this).width(270).height(250).appendTo('#webcam');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Post what you've tried with the interval

Comment: Just wrap your code in a function and do setInterval('yourFunction', 2000) // 2 seconds

Comment: Try moving `var imgPaht = "http://www.radiobaiano.it/webcam.jpg";` above `setInterval(load, 5000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:

You should clear the previous image before place new image.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   setInterval(load, 5000);
   var imgPaht = "http://www.radiobaiano.it/webcam.jpg";
   function load() {
    console.log("inside load");
    $('<img src="'+ imgPaht+'?'+new Date().getTime() +'">').load(function () {
       // use this only if you have the new image to be in #webcam
        $('#webcam').empty();
        $(this).width(270).height(250).appendTo('#webcam');
    });
  }
});
```

Method 2:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   setInterval(load, 5000);
   var imgPaht = "http://www.radiobaiano.it/webcam.jpg";
   function load() {
     $("#imageId").remove();
     $('<img id="imageId" src="'+ imgPaht+'?'+new Date().getTime() +'">').load(function      () {          
       $(this).width(270).height(250).appendTo('#webcam');
     });
   }
});
```

Method 3:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
          setInterval(load, 5000);
          var imgPaht = "http://www.radiobaiano.it/webcam.jpg";
        function load() {

         if($('#webcam img').length == 0)
         {
            $('<img id="imageId" src="'+ imgPaht+'?'+new Date().getTime() +'">').load(function () {
           // use this only if you have the new image to be in #webcam
            $('#webcam').empty();
            $(this).width(270).height(250).appendTo('#webcam');
            });
         }
         else
         {
            $('#webcam img').attr('src',imgPaht);
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {     

  var imgPaht = "http://www.sito.it/webcam.jpg";
  window.setInterval(function(){
    $('<img src="'+ imgPaht +'">').load(function() {
      $(this).width(270).height(250).appendTo('#webcam');
    });
  }, 5000);

});

</script>
```

Comment: What is the path of the new image?

Comment: what could i do for replace the older image?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is fine-ish. Couple of issues though:

1. You don't initially call the `load()` function hence you have to wait 5 seconds before the image will appear initially.
2. You are using `.appendTo` without clearing existin contents, hence images are just added over and over to the placeholder and not replacing the older ones.

Solution to both would be:

```
setInterval(load, 5000);
var imgPaht = "http://www.miosito.it/webcam.jpg";
function load() {
    var placeholder = $("#webcam");
    placeholder.html("");
    $('<img src="'+ imgPaht +'">').load(function () {
        $(this).width(270).height(250).appendTo(placeholder);
    });
}
load();
```

The `.html("")` will clear contents and calling `load()` will show the initial image.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/g4t9e/1/).

Answer (score -1):

Use `setTimeout()`:

```
var t = setTimeout(code, interval);
```

The interval is in milliseconds, so 5 seconds would be 5000:

```
var t = setTimeout($('img').attr('src', 'new-path'), 5000);
```

Comment: User wants to repeat not delay only :)